# Obviously silly mistake trying to pass a value from an Axios response to data object in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm sure this is ridiculously simple, but I'm having trouble passing a response from an Axios request to the data object to use elsewhere. It's currently just returning whatever I set as the default in the data object (in this instance, null). Help please! It's greatly appreciated.

My Vue code:

```
var thing = new Vue({
    el: '#el',
    data: {
        message: null,
    },
    components: ...
    template: ...
    methods: {
        thing() {
            ...
        }
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('/is-logged')
        .then(response => {
            if(response.data.status == 'error') {
                this.message = response.data.message;
            }
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    },

    mounted() {
        if (!this.message) {
            console.log(this.message);
            this.thing();
        }
    }
});
```

The response I get back from is_logged:

```
{"message":"You are not authorised","status":"error"}
```

Comment: What happens if you take out the if?

Comment: If the response status code indicates an error then the promise will reject, so you need to handle that in the `catch` handler.

Comment: It still returns null with the if statement removed. Oddly enough, if I add the console.log directly after the response and before the catch handler, it works. The problem seems to be passing it outside the Axios function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're logging its value before the AJAX request completes (since the component will be `mounted` before you get the response from the request in `created`).

Try putting `console.log(this.message)` at the end of your `then` callback.

Comment: Thanks, this makes total sense. If I wanted to reuse this.message elsewhere in the component though, what would the proper way to do/refactor this?

Comment: What do you mean by "reuse `this.message` elsewhere"? You can use it wherever you want, so long as you use it after the request has completed (or if you bind it in your UI, the UI will automatically update whenever it updates).